# MASM & Java get values from two dimensional array

Tags: assembly, java-native-interface, x86-64, masm

I want to get first value of two dimensional array (array[0][0]). I've function declared in Java as follow:

```
public native void function(int[][] array, int width, int height);
```

I'm creating application for Windows x64, so I'm using Windows x64 ABI.

After performing :

```
    mov env,rcx ; 1st argument
    ; according to doc 2nd arg. is Java Object so i omitt this variable
    mov jArray,r8 ; 3rd argument
    mov width, r9 ; 4th argument
    mov rbx, qWORD PTR[rsp + 40] ; 5th arg array.length (height)
    mov height, rbx ; 5th


    mov rax, [rcx]  ; get location of JNI function table
    mov funTable, rax
    mov rdx, r8 ; set second arg as jArray
    mov r8, 0   ; set index of row
    call qword ptr[rax + 173 * 8] ; invoke GetObjectArrayElement()
    mov rbx, rax ; set return value to rbx
    mov rcx, env 
    mov r8, 0    ; paramter isCopy
    mov r10, funTable
    call qword ptr[r10 + 187 * 8] ; invoke GetIntArrayElements()
```

After last call i should get the proper value of array[0][0] but instead of this I'm getting random values (each time i redebug this function).
What am I doing wrong (please mark my mistake - I want to learn).
I may add that I was searching for some kind of documentation/examples but with poor effect.

Comment: Shouldn't `mov rbx, rax` be `mov rdx, rax`? You want to pass the value returned by `GetObjectArrayElement` into `GetIntArrayElements`. Also - no, `GetIntArrayElements` would not return the value of `array[0][0]`. It would return the address of a chunk of memory containing all the values in `array[0]`.

Comment: @Michael I was assuming that the beggining of the table contains the first element. Okey, so according to what You have said, I will have to move pointer by `QWORD` value each time i want to read new value?

Comment: Please also tell me, why when i'm performing (after your fixes) line : `call qword ptr[r10 + 187 * 8]` and call `ret` everything works fine, but when i try to do call `qword ptr[r10 + 187 * 8]` -> `mov r15,rax` -> `ret` then `ret` instruction throw access violation error. I can't find it anywhere ..

Comment: `r15` is a callee-save register in the Windows 64-bit calling convention, so its value must be the same when you return from your function as it was when you entered your function.

Comment: And, although probably not related to your crash, you should always call `Release<Type>ArrayElements` when you're done using the pointer returned by `Get<Type>ArrayElements`.

Comment: You should probably avoid using static storage to save/restore `rcx`.  It would be easy to make this function re-entrant by using stack space.  And don't forget to reserve shadow space for your callees, unless you're using a custom calling convention for hand-written asm functions that doesn't use Windows x64 shadow space.

Comment: Have you tried just writing this in C or C++ and looking at the resulting compiler output (with optimization enabled)?  You should get working (and reasonably efficient) asm that way, which follows the calling convention correctly.  You can compare it with your code and see the difference.

Comment: @Michael Last question: Before performing an `Release<Type>ArrayElements` as You said, and copy back changed values to the array in Java application. How to save this changed values? I've come to `mov qword ptr[r11+r9], rax` solution  (when in rax i have modified value, which i want to write to this part of memeory) but apparently it is not working.

Comment: You would have to pass the correct value for the `mode` parameter, [as described in the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/functions.html#Release_PrimitiveType_ArrayElements_routines). In your case you probably want mode 0.